# Generic types on dispatcher job in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm doing a way to dispatch use case.. It's working very well, but I'm blocked with generic types in swift.

An abstract class responsible to register the observable channels, needs capture the generic handle Output to look if it's a handle success or error, driving the correctly channel handle.

At this moment, my cast generate an exception:

Could not cast value of type

> 'ios_pokedex_clean.ValueOutput<ios_pokedex_clean.Landing>'
> (0x205ea7900) to 'ios_pokedex_clean.Output<Any>' (0x205ea8010).

The Landing is the class expected for view and is knowledge only in the View.

But I don't need to know what is the class in Output when I stay in BaseViewController. Only if notification.object is class Output type.
What I need do to get the behaviors expected?

```
class Landing : Any{ //it's a way?
...
}
```

[image: stack running]

Comment: What is the signature of the `handleSuccess(value:)` method? That looks like you need to know the type of `value` in order to call it. What is the parametric type of `Output` used for (is it the type of `value`?)

Comment: Swift generic types are not covariant which is why the cast fails.  Generics are probably not the answer you are looking for here.  A protocol or sub classing may be more appropriate

Comment: @RobNapier func handleSuccess(value: Any?)

Comment: @Paulw11 thanks for helping. I will go think about..

Comment: This much use of Any is a sign of a real problem in the design. Especially if you see `Any?` show up, you're going to have a lot of problems. It's a nightmare of a type because it can implicitly promote in bizarre ways when mixed with generics (it can automatically turn into `Any??`, `Any???` and worse, and you wind up in a sea of nested Optional). I'd start by exploring replacing NotificationCenter with a more type-safe solution like delegates, closures, or even Combine Publishers.

Comment: This view layer, i'm using a adapter pattern to organize the behaviours of children view's. Know the data as a any isnt't a problem to me in this layer. The ValueOutput are assembled, proteded and dispatch in my framework. I just needed get object ValueOutput, to know what channel to notify.

Answer (score -1):

Thinking about... that's works to me was:

```
@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification) {
    let state = ValueOutput(value: notification.object.self)
    if(state.isError()) {
        handleThrowable(error: state.error)
    } else {
        handleSuccess(value: state.value)
    }
}
```

```
ValueOutput(value: notification.object.self)
```

avoiding cast.